# How to get Bearer token to connect to the Azure Logic App?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-logic-apps, bearer-token

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/) you have access to the Azure Logic App REST APIs and you can call them.

When I click on the "Try It" button Microsoft generates a correct bearer token for me.

[image]

And the query result is successful.
By copying the bearer token inside Postman I can get the result again inside it,

But,

How can I generate this bearer token inside C# Application via the HttpClient library or Postman?

How can I find the info to generate the token?

**UPDATE**

Let me update the post for more details
I want to use this library [IPB.LogicApp.Standard.Testing](https://github.com/michaelstephensonuk/IntegrationPlaybook-LogicApp-Standard-Testing)
 and it needs

- ClientID
- ClientSecret
- TenantId

to generate a bearer token.
I want to know How can I find this info to generate the correct bearer token as Microsoft did? because via the Azure portal I have provided this info but the bearer token does not work (invalid) when I use the Microsoft bearer token it works (valid).

How can I get those data for an Azure Logic App workflow correctly to generate the right bearer token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re hell bent on using HTTP requests directly, you need to use one of the methods contained within this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

To get the client ID and secret, you need to read through this documentation, it provides the necessary steps for doing so ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

If you're using C#, rather than calling the REST API's directly, my suggestion would be to use the Azure Management SDK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/azure/sdk/resource-management

From an auth perspective, all of the examples, etc. on how to do so are contained here and there are multiple methods and a sequence that the SDK goes through when determining the authentication method ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication

This is a basic example of a program that gives me all of the LogicApps in my default subscription and it's authenticating via the user I have selected in the following Visual Studio preference ...

[image: VS Preferences]

You'll need to make sure you add these three nuget packages ...

```
Azure.Identity
Azure.ResourceManager
Azure.ResourceManager.Logic
```

... and this is the example ...

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Logic;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureManagement
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetLogicApps().Wait();
        }

        static async Task GetLogicApps()
        {
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var armClient = new ArmClient(credential);
            var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

            var logicAppsEnumerator = subscription.GetLogicWorkflowsAsync().GetAsyncEnumerator();

            try
            {
                while (await logicAppsEnumerator.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    var logicApp = logicAppsEnumerator.Current;
                    Console.WriteLine(logicApp.Data.Name);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                await logicAppsEnumerator.DisposeAsync();
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

You haven't been specific about what you actually want to do but I suspect you'll be able to do what you want via this approach.

The code will also be secure whether you're coding in VS or deployed in Azure, as long as you use managed identities of course.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer but I have updated my post for more details. Could you please check it? My problem is finding the correct ClientID, ClientSecret & TenantId for generating a correct bearer token for an Azure Logic App like Microsoft can do but I dont!

Comment: I’ve provided all of the information you need. Follow the bouncing ball in the documentation when it comes to the authentication link. Also, you say you provided that information via Azure. If you created an app and assigned it via RBAC then there should be no problem. Also, where are you planning on hosting your code? In an Azure service like functions?!!

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link to how to setup an app registration in Azure.  That's how you get the client ID and secret.